# JavaFX program locks/freezes whilst running

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, freeze

I'm trying to create a JavaFX program, which is working - but I am trying to get a progress bar to update whilst it is running.

However, the program just seems to freeze and locks up until it has finished processing.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get the program not to freeze whilst running - and to get the progress bar to update whilst it processes?

Thanks

Comment: Put it in a `Thread` or use `Platform.runLater(() -> progressBar.setProgress(progressValue));`

Comment: Please post some code showing what you're doing. Ideally you should create a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be executed directly and which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't know who just downvoted a javafx question i asked 1 1/2 year ago, but please quit that childish behaviour. I didn't downvote anything in this  question.

Comment: Thank you WonderWorld, I thought that might be the method to use. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Which one you are using, to put the code in a thread or the Platform.runlater?

Comment: Let me put that as an answer, then you can hit the green check. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the progressbar progress in a `Platform.runLater(()-> progressBar.setProgress(progressValue));` so it will be executed at a later point in time.