# Javafx : setRotate and setTranslate in a for loop

Tags: animation, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and encountered a problem with the rotating animation while trying to write a Rubik's cube solving program.
I know JavaFX provides some classes for the animation ,but instead of using them, I wanted to try my own approach initially.
Following is the rough idea of my code :

```
for(90 times)
{

 cube.setRotate(cube.getRotate() + 1);

 try{Thread.sleep(100);}
  catch{InterruptedException e) {Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}

}
```

By rotating the cube only one degree at a time and using time delay and loop appropriately,
 I expected to see something similar to rotating animation.
But the result I get is that the cube in the screen doesn't change with each setRotate() in the for loop, it only changes after the loop is over and therefore it changes 90 degrees at one time after 90*100 milliseconds.
I'm wondering if there is a method that can refresh the output in the screen each time using the setRotate() method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX program locks/freezes whilst running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941347/javafx-program-locks-freezes-whilst-running)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid the mechanisms which are designed to make animations. Don't you think there is a reason that they exist?

With your code you are blocking the JavaFX application thread and the resulting behaviour is described in all documents dealing with this issue.